# Add DataAnnotations to entity class using database first approach

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, ef-database-first

I'm trying to migrate a large (+100000 LoC) WPF application from [Telerik Data Access](http://www.telerik.com/data-access) to Entity Framework 6.1.3.

I'm new to Entity Framework and wondering how to **generate** data annotations for my POCO's.

Adding them manually is not an option because i would have to do this for a few hundred views with many columns.

The Data annotations are not only important for data validation but also for the excel export functionally. Entity Framework maps both Date and DateTime2 (SQL Server) to DateTime (c#). The excel export method uses the data annotations to pick the correct cell format (eg. 2016-06-27 instead of 2016-06-15 00:00:00.000)

The desired result should look like this:

```
private DateTime? _transactionDate;
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Date)]
public virtual DateTime? TransactionDate
{
    get
    {
        return this._transactionDate;
    }
    set
    {
        this._transactionDate = value;
    }
}
```

**Questions:**
How can I enabled DataAnnotations in Entity Framework 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

try taking a look at [ef power tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj593170.aspx) it will get you part of the way there. The rest I think you are going to have to do manually.

Comment: It is not recommended to use Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 anymore. Last update was 10/12/2013, it does not support visual studio 2015. Consider this piece of software as deprecated.

Anyway, I can generate POCOs with default Entity Framework Designer as well. The problem is that i don't know how to add DataAnnotations to the generated classes.